# Change column width size in command output

Tags: linux, text-formatting

I have the output from a command in which some text is hidden due to the column width size; are there any commands that can help display all of the output in that column? Currently, I use the `grep` command to fetch this output.

`LON IGA NG` is a large word in the `INT` and `EXT` row, but it is only displayed because of the column size.

```
|In Use |Int       |Ext       |Service   |Time      |TOS       |Encaps    |Interface |Dir
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|enable |LON_IGA_NG|LON_IGA_NG|All IP    |Anytime   |Ignore ToS|Ignore    |Any       |bidir
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That is it that produces this output? Some kind of database query?

Comment: We can't say because we see only the result, how is this result produced? I guess you have to change the command you use to get this result, to fetch data in wider columns.

Comment: This is how the command generates output. This is not a database query, and there is no other command to change the column width. I can use linux commands like grep to change the output along with this command. So I'm looking for a linux command that will accomplish this.

Comment: Are you asking for help to write a tool that can read the string `LON_IGA_NG` as input and somehow output some much longer string that some other tool truncated to print `LON_IGA_NG`? If so - no, nothing can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any general facility that would do that; it just depends on how the programmer wrote their program.  Some things to try:

1. Read the man page or other documentation for the program if it exists.  There may be a command line argument to set column size.
2. Make your terminal emulator very wide.  Some programs query the width of the terminal and adjust their columns accordingly.
3. Output to a file instead of to the screen.